# convert SQLQuery into django query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How to convert this query into django queryset ?

```
SELECT body, ( SELECT COUNT(status_id) FROM queue WHERE queue.primary_ref_id = messages.Id AND status_id = 2) as count FROM messages
```

I am new to django framework. Please help me to fix this..

this is my Queue Model:

```
class Queue(models.Model):
possible_action = models.ForeignKey(PossibleActions)
primary_ref = models.ForeignKey(Message)
secondary_ref = models.ForeignKey(Contacts)
status = models.ForeignKey(Statuses)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'queue'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.possible_action) + str(self.status) + str(self.primary_ref) + str(self.secondary_ref)
```

this is my Message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
body = models.TextField()
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
cell_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True)
received_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
device_id = models.IntegerField()


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'messages'

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.body) + str(self.cell_number)
```

**Updated Solution:**
here is my searching:

```
Message.objects.extra(
    select={
        'published_entry_count': "SELECT COUNT(status_id) FROM queue WHERE queue.primary_ref_id = messages.Id AND status_id = 2"
    },
    where=["(SELECT COUNT(status_id) FROM queue WHERE queue.primary_ref_id = messages.Id AND status_id = 2) < 1"]

)
```

this is what i want but still a problem is that it would not show me all messages. It only show me those whose count is 0.

Comment: What do your Django models look like, and what's the structure of your database tables? Also, what are `body` and `status_id` in this case?

Comment: @bouteillebleu i has edit my post ..

Answer (score -1):

you can write you sql query in Django like this

```
Model.object.raw('SELECT body, ( SELECT COUNT(status_id) FROM queue WHERE queue.primary_ref_id = messages.Id AND status_id = 2) as count FROM messages')
```

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key